# convert multi variable from string to decimal in c#.net in asp.net threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 2 or maybe more than  2 string variable like below

```
string a = csvalue[7].Replace(" ", ""); //a="‏120641"
string b = csvalue[9].Replace(" ", "") ;//b="‏"221707‏‏‏‏
decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal(a) + Convert.ToDecimal(b)
```

but it have exception:" threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'"

i try

```
       enter code here 
       string one = "‏120641‏‏‏‏";
        string two = "‏221707‏‏‏‏";
        string three = "123548";
       
        Double iOne = 0;
        Double iTwo = 0;
        Double ithree = 0;

        Double.TryParse(one, out iOne);
        Double.TryParse(two, out iTwo);
        Double.TryParse(three, out ithree);
```

and it dosent work for iOne,iTwo
please help me

Comment: your input has some `RLM`-unicode-markers that break the formatting. you have to replace those as well, not just spaces.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fenzWO it runs for me, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Costa: copy&paste the code from here to your fiddle and you'll see the problem

Comment: try printing `one.Length` - it's 11 instead of the expected 6

Comment: And this is why actual code in the question is much better than an image of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some (invisible) unicode chars which are not digits, so cannot be parsed. You could remove them for example with Linq and `char.IsDigit`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string one = "‏120641‏‏‏‏";
        string two = "‏221707‏‏‏‏";
        string three = "123548";
        one = new string(one.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
        two = new string(two.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
        three = new string(three.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
       
        Double iOne = 0;
        Double iTwo = 0;
        Double ithree = 0;

        Double.TryParse(one, out iOne);
        Double.TryParse(two, out iTwo);
        Double.TryParse(three, out ithree);
        Console.WriteLine(iOne);
        Console.WriteLine(iTwo);
        Console.WriteLine(ithree);
    }
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zgv1Pt)